# How to handle several windows form

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm doing a small project to store movies. I'm using three windows form, a intro form, a main form and a new movie form. I also have a class that I call MovieManager that is the heart of the application. My problem is that I'm not sure how I should handle this windows.

Let's say I want the application to start with the intro form and when the user click on the OK-button the main form should appear. What is the best way to do this? Should I in the Program.cs create an object of the MovieManager class that show and hide the different windows form or should I in the Program.cs just start by showing the intro form?

Comment: It's up to you, whatever the user will need most - show first I guess.

Comment: I want to start with the intro form, but I just wondered if I should start with the MovieManager that isn't a form or should I start with a intr form. If I start with the Moviemanager, my thought was if I could control the visibility of all forms from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do all staff in Program.cs when starting application. Show your IntroForm as dialog. If user clicks OK, then start main application form, otherwise close application.

```
static void Main()
{
    IntroForm introForm = new IntroForm();
    if (introForm.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
    {
        Application.Exit();
        return;

    }

    Application.Run(new MainForm());
}
```

If you need single `MovieManager` instance for all these forms, then you can create it in Main method and pass same instance to `IntroForm` and `MainForm`:

```
MovieManager movieManager = new MovieManager();

IntroForm introForm = new IntroForm(movieManager);
if (introForm.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK)
{
    Application.Exit();
    return;
}

Application.Run(new MainForm(movieManager));
```

Also you can implement `MovieManager` as [Singleton](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx), which will be accessible everywhere via static property `MovieManager.Instance`.

Comment: I'm testing the first alternative in your answer. I have a OK button in the IntroForm, but nothing happens when I click it?

Comment: Select your OK button and at properties window set `DialogResult` property to `OK`. Or you can manually set DialogResult property of IntroForm on this button's click event handler.

Comment: Is there a simple way to center the each form?

Comment: Yes, there is a property `StartPosition` of form. You can set it to `CenterScreen`

Comment: When I click on a button in the MainForm  to create an object and to show the MovieForm, isn't this enough: MovieForm movieForm = new MovieForm(); ??

Comment: You need also to show your form. Use `movieForm.Show()` or `movieForm.ShowDialog()` (if it should be modal)

Answer (score 1):

What you call intro form, I should call a splash screen. In the program.cs I should just pop-up the splash screen (with a logo, title and info about the application, version number, etc.). The splash screen is shown for a certain amount of time (use a timer for this, or Thread.Sleep is alos possible altough a bit heavy).

When the splash screen closes show the MainForm is shown a from there you can instantiate a MovieManager or use a static MovieManager (it depends on its use). From the mainform you can then just instantiate and show new movie form(s).

We use a piece of code something like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
  try
  {
    SplashScreen.ShowSplashScreen();
    Application.DoEvents();
    SplashScreen.WaitForVisibility(.5);
    bool starting = true;
    while (starting)
    {
      try
      {
        SplashScreen.SetStatus("Initialize mainform...");
        starting = false;
        Application.Run(new MainForm());
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
        if (starting)
          starting = XtraMessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Fout bij initialiseren", MessageBoxButtons.RetryCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1) == DialogResult.Retry;
        else
          throw (ex);
      }
    }
  }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
    if (ex is object)
      XtraMessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Algemene fout", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error, MessageBoxDefaultButton.Button1);
  }
}
```

And code in the splashscreen (excerpt) looks like this:

```
if (_splashForm == null)
{
  ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(RunSplashForm, null);
  while (_splashForm == null || _splashForm.IsHandleCreated == false)
  {
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
  }
}
```

Maybe these links will also provide you some usefull information:

http://www.reflectionit.nl/Articles/Splash.aspx

And we used this as the basis for our own code:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5454/A-Pretty-Good-Splash-Screen-in-C

Answer (score 0):

There are different ways to show a new form. you can use MdiWinForm first you must change IsMdiContainer property to true then use these codes in the MainForm :

```
  Form2 f2;    

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (f2 == null) {
       f2 = new Form2();
       f2.MdiParent = this;
       f2.FormClosed += delegate { f2 = null; };
       f2.Show();
    }
    else {
       f2.Activate();
    }
}
```